# Получить содержание ячейки оперативной памяти процесса моей программы с помощью .Net

Tags: c#, .net, память, виртуальная-память, системное-программирование

Я знаю что можно получить объем виртуальной памяти(Process.PagedMemorySize). Но как получить именно то что содержится в ячейке памяти процесса. Возможно ли это сделать, если да то как это сделать на c# с помощью .Net

Answer (score 5):

Да это можно сделать используя WinAPI:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern Int32 ReadProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress,[In, Out] byte[] buffer, UInt32 size, out IntPtr lpNumberOfBytesRead);

public byte[] ReadProcessMemory(IntPtr MemoryAddress, uint bytesToRead, out int bytesRead, IntPtr handle)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bytesToRead];
    IntPtr ptrBytesRead;
    ReadProcessMemory(handle, MemoryAddress, buffer, bytesToRead, out ptrBytesRead);
    int result = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
    bytesRead = ptrBytesRead.ToInt32();
    return buffer;
}
```

Comment: А для DllImport какая библиотека нужна?

Comment: По моему вот эта System.Runtime.InteropServices (пишу по памяти могу и ошибаться)

Comment: А как я могу одновременно сделать #include <windows.h> и using System.Runtime.InteropServices.

Comment: На сколько я знаю вы не можете в C# использовать подобную конструкцию: #include <windows.h>